# Массив байтов в строку с русскими символами

Tags: кодировка, java

Есть изначально какая-то строка с русскими символами, к примеру:

```
String str = "тест";
```

Получаем массив байтов:

```
byte[] arr = str.getBytes()
```

Так вот, если посмотрим на получившийся массив, там будут вместо стандартных ASCII кодов отрицательные числа, т.к. байт от -128 до 127.

И вопрос: как, имея эти отрицательные числа, получить ту же строку с русскими символами?
Так как при переводе обычным `String(arr)` получаем из отрицательных неверные значения (�).

Спасибо.

Comment: У класса String есть перегруженный конструктор с аргументом кодировки - не пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте указание кодировки при конвертации строк в байты и обратно. Например:

```
byte[] arr =str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

и соответственно

```
String str = new String(arr, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, если получать байты уже в нужной кодировке. 
А что делать, если они получаются, к примеру, из файла: 

    Files.readAllBytes()

Тогда нет возможности указать нужную кодировку и получается что, к примеру, текст "тест" будет представлен: [-14, -27, -15, -14]. 
Возможно из этого получить изначальное сообщение?

Comment: @digwnews Очевидно, что вы должны знать кодировку текста в файле. Если кодировка заранее неизвестна, то можно попытаться определить ее автоматически, путем анализа входных данных.

Comment: Так и есть, спасибо!